# Is there a difference in connecting a fax to a UK phone line compared to a European one?

Tags: connection, fax

i know the power sockets are diffrent, but how will a fax machine be connected up in the uk compared to abelgian or dutch one?

The ones we have are the ones in the below pictures "Phone" but in the uk they seem to be the same as the adsl connector of that picture.

[image: telefoonlijn]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK phone connector is bigger than the ADSL (RJ11) jack. Lots of info at Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_telephone_sockets

With regards to connecting, say, a UK fax machine to the Dutch phone system - there are differences in the electrical spec and so there are no guarantees it will work - for example, the fax may not detect incoming calls or be able to 'pick up' the line to send. One hope may be if the fax machine has a 'country' setting. Perhaps someone here has practical experience of doing this - I have a Dutch ex-colleague so I'll send her an email and update here later.

Update: My Dutch ex-colleague says "won't work properly" but didn't elaborate.

Comment: +1 there are adaptors like [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Swiss-World-Modem-Adapter-Switzerland/dp/B000IV285Q), but there's no guaranteed that is going to work, especially with a fax. There seem to be additional quirks needing special provisions to ensure a device actually rings - see [here](http://www.reveal.co.uk/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=80_155)